# Is there any app like virtual drive of farstone?

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there any app like "virtual drive" of farstone?
We can use this app to create virtual CD/ DVD for playing without disks on CD/DVD drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create ISOs of disks  with

`dd if=/dev/cdrom of=~/disk.iso`

You will likely have to adjust the path of the cdrom drive to meet your system (I have seen them named all kinds of things.

To mount an existing ISO

`mount -o loop ~/disk.iso /media/path`

Where media path is the spot you wish to mount it.

Comment: It helps! More simple way, I use bareso burning app to create iso image. Right click the iso image then chose "Open with Disk Image Mounter" the image will be mounted and run.